# Drag NSView anywhere on screen (no window)

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, nsview

I want to drag out a copy of the menu bar icon anywhere on the screen. I NSStatusItem uses a custom view and I've been able to have it display an icon in the menu bar. My application doesn't use an NSWindow as you may guess.

I am able to drag and drop it but it gets cut off by the tiny view in the menu bar.

[image: menubar icon]

For example in Clear for Mac you can just drag stuff anywhere around the screen outside of its own window:

[Screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/0e0o3T433h0N)

On iOS with UIView this apparently works by clipToBounds:NO but I don't know of any equivalent for an NSView on OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `-[NSView dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:]`?

Comment: Thanks this worked! I thought it'd be much harder than this! Is that the only way of doing this?

Comment: Btw, this seems to interfere with the mouseDragged event. It doesn't get called after mouseDown gets called.

Comment: As far as whether it's the only way, there is a convenience method for dragging a file, but that's basically the same.  If you really wanted, you could hack some way using a transparent overlay window I guess, but I don't know why you'd want to.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but I wasn't sure if that would be an acceptable solution. I think I will try that. I can't think of any other way. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need mouseDragged events after the dragging session starts?  Have you read about the NSDraggingSource protocol?

Comment: No I have not heard about about the NSDraggingSource protocol but it seems like it does everything that `mouseDown`, `mouseDragged`, and `mouseUp` do. I use mouseDragged to calculate the dragging distance in real time. Should I use the NSDraggingSource protocol? If yes, why so?

Comment: NSDraggingSource seems like it's what they intended you to use when dragging an image.  There's a saying, "don't fight the framework."

Comment: I just found this [sample code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Listings/CocoaDragAndDrop_DragDropImageView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000384-CocoaDragAndDrop_DragDropImageView_m-DontLinkElementID_6) that uses NSDraggingSource for dragging too. So I should definitely leave out mouseDragged and go with NSDraggingSource methods. Thanks!